# Can an Angular ng-mousover event trigger ng-style on multiple elements?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm currently learning Angular and I have a question.

I have two divs that change their background color on triggering the `ng-mouseover` directive. here is a little snippet of the two divs.

```
<div id="mid-left" class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="row  left-section" ng-repeat="variance in variances.variance_data" ng-style="background" ng-mouseover="background = setColor(variance)" ng-mouseleave="background = {}">
</div>

<div id="mid-right" class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="row right-section" ng-repeat="variance in variances.variance_data" ng-style="background" ng-mouseover="background = setColor(variance)" ng-mouseleave="background = {}">
</div>
```

I assumed that the `background` variable I declared in the directives would be added to the existing `$scope`.

With the two divs being bound to the 'same variable' (in my mind) I assumed they would both change on when either `ng-mouseover` event was triggered.

Any and all help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use the CSS :hover pseudo-class? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: The divs are both part of seperate ng-repeats so the color is defined by which iteration of the ng-repeat is currently executing. Im not sure how I would do that with a psudeo class.

Comment: How many colours in your scheme, just alternating or loads?

Comment: Four at present but I wanted to allow it to allocate colours from the rainbow for n iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `background = setColor(variance)`, you should be defining a `background` variable in your local scope, and creating a function on the scope called `setColor` that alters the local scope `background` value.  You'd then want to build a function to clear that value, as opposed to setting it to an empty object within your view.

Comment: So is that because the background variable that i was instantiating in my markup wasn't in the $scope ? It doesn't get added dynamically? Its just in that elements scope or something?

Comment: Having moved that out into js functions both are triggering but now I have ALL rows of the ng-repeat changing to the color of the row that I am mouseovering! I need to reference the event I think.. Thanks heaps

Comment: I was just going to suggest using an array of colours in your $scope and then each row would be able to use `background[$index]` and each row can have it's own colour

Comment: Now each row of the ng-repeat iteration calls the same function that returns the current value of a single local scope background color variable. This makes every row change to the color for the current mouse overed row. Can i use $Index to make sure the other rows backgrounds stay white? hmmm.

Comment: ideally, you'd be using a directive with isolate scope to do this, which would would achieve what you are looking for.. with actually very few lines of code.

Comment: That sounds like the angular approach I was looking for, thanks for the nudge :)

Comment: Apologies, side tracked, thanks for taking the time I appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-style` takes..

> Expression which evals to an object whose keys are CSS style names and
>   values are corresponding values for those CSS keys

I think it's impossible to say why it doesn't work without seeing what's returned from `setColor(variance)`

Comment: {'background-color': '#48036f'}

Comment: As a string or an object?

Comment: an object, It works I just couldn't work out the correct angular approach to getting the two divs to trigger on either ng-mouseover event being triggered.